# Where can I find South and South East Asian fish fingerlings in Europe?

Tags: farming, fish

I am interested in farming South and Southeast Asian fish species (e.g., Labeo catla, Labeo rohita, Heteropneustes fossilis, Channa punctata, etc.) in my backyard pond in Germany.

How can I obtain their fingerlings?